# How to close a Form from a Form in C#?

Tags: c#

I have 3 Forms. From Form1 I open Form3 and Form4 with a button. But than when I press a Button on Form4 I want to close both Form4 and Form3.(Don't worry about Form2)

Form1:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Form3 frm3 = new Form3();
        frm3.Show();

        Form4 frm4 = new Form4();
        frm4.Show();



    }
```

Form4:

```
private void button12_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
    this.Close();
    //Plus close Form3
```

Comment: You should name your forms and controls.

Comment: You need to pass the form to the other form.

Comment: @TheBeardedLlama No mine is different

Comment: Iterate over the `Application.OpenForms` collection and close the forms you want to close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Form1:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { 
   Form3 frm3 = new Form3();
   frm3.Show(); 

   Form4 frm4 = new Form4(frm3);
   frm4.Show();
 }
```

Form4:

```
Form3 mFrm3Ref;
public Form4(Form3 frm){
    mFrm3Ref = frm;
    //and other initializing stuff 
} 
private void button12_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
   mFrm3Ref.Close() ;
   this.Close();
}
```

Comment: It doesn't recognize mFrm3Ref.Close();

Comment: @MártonGergő updated my answer

Comment: It has a problem now at #Form4 frm4 = new Form4# There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'frm' of 'Form4.Form4(Form3)'

Comment: @MártonGergő my bad edited the post.